# How to get Zend Studio auto-complete working with CakePHP models?

Tags: php, cakephp, zend-studio, eclipse-pdt, cakephp-2.2

I would like Zend Studio to recognize the class type for all the controller's models, in a CakePHP 2.x project.

This is how I currently do it.

```
class MyController extends AppController
{
      public $uses = array('Scan');

      public function index()
      {
          /* @var $scan Scan */
          $scan = $this->Scan;
          // do stuff...
      }
}
```

The above works fine, and Zend will refactor all references to the Scan class correctly, but this is a pain because it has to be done in every action.

I'd like to do this instead.

```
class MyController extends AppController
{
      public $uses = array('Scan');

      /** @var Scan */
      public $Scan;

      public function index()
      {
          // do stuff...
          $this->Scan->.....
      }
}
```

When I tried to declare it as a property then $this->Scan is `null`, and Cake isn't loading the model.

Is there a way to declare it as a property with a phpDoc type without breaking CakePHP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CakePHP will automatically attach this varialbe to your Controller and what you're essentially doing is redeclaring it.

I am not completely shure how this is done internally in Cake but have you tried declaring `$Scan` before `$uses`?
Another way would be to redeclare the Controller's constructor to hadnle this but that seems a bit too far-fetched.

Total refactoring capability is something we're still waiting for and it will come with total adoptance of the PSR standards and especially namespaces.

Edit:
Here's a nifty (hack) way to add autoComplete for Helpers in Views. This **will work for CakePHP >= 2** and **only in Views**. Also I've used this only in Eclipse but I suppose it should work in any IDE since it is OOP and PHPDoc based.

"All you need to do: is to create a file called "ThisHelper.php" in the `app/View` directory (not in `View/Helper`) with the following contents:

```
App::uses('AppHelper', 'Helper');
/**
 * this Helper
 *
 * @property Html $Html
 * @property Session $Session
 * @property Form $Form
 */
class this extends AppHelper
{
    var $Html;
    var $Session;
    var $Form;

    public function __contruct()
    {
        $this->Html = new HtmlHelper($View);
        $this->Session = new SessionHelper($View);        
        $this->Form = new FormHelper($View);        
    }
}

$this = new this();
```

To add support for other helpers (Cake core or not) just add them as variables to this class, for example if you want to add PaginatorHelper do:

```
@property Paginator $Paginator
....
var $Paginator;
.....
public function __contruct()
{
    .............
    $this->Paginator = new PaginatorHelper($View);
}
```

Probably the best thing to do is to add properties for all CoreHelpers available in CakePHP.
Of course it will work with any custom Helpers if you add them. You do not need to include this file in any PHP Script - just add it to the `app/View/` directory.

Comment: It looks like Cake does not load the model until it's first used. It catches this with the `__get` callback of the controller. When first used the model will be loaded. If I declare it locally, then `__get` is never called. I might be able to do a hack in my AppController to fix this, but I haven't decided if it's worth doing.

Comment: Well yes, you could redeclare the `__get()` callback but firstly ask your self if this is worth doing just to autocomplete working in with Models? 
I can share a nifty trick about getting this to work with helpers which I find very neat. Just post a comment so that I can share it.

Comment: wow, I've got to try this. Thanks! Doesn't the IDE complain that this is a reserved word, but I guess that doesn't matter cause you're not using the file.

Comment: @BorislavSabev, this works great, tks, just one qsn, the autocomplete of `$this` does not work, I mean when I write `$th` it does not suggest me $this, though after manually writing `$this->` it already suggests the available helpers. I believe `$th..` autocomplete should work based on `$this = new this();` line in ThisHelper, maybe u have some clue why it does not? tks

Comment: @dav well I am not sure. It used to work for me. The studio should auto complete the word `$this` without our modifications.
  This is essentially a hack to fool Eclipse into reading the properties and methods of the CakePHP Helpers.